# I get a blank output when i am using c:foreach

Tags: jsp, jstl

Code in the jsp page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page import="GeneralClasses.FooClass" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:forEach var="fromArray" items="${array}">
        <p>
            ${fromArray}
        </p>
    </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the class that stores the attribute `array`

```
package GeneralClasses;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FooClass {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
    String[] array = {"a","b","java","programming","OS"};
    request.setAttribute("array", array);
  }    
}
```

I get a blank page when i run the jsp file. What do i do to use the `c:foreach` tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When JSTL tags don't run, then either you don't have JSTL installed at all, or you're using the ancient JSTL 1.0 version which has a different taglib URI. Easiest way to verify if JSTL has run or not is to open the page in browser, do rightclick and *View Source*. If you see JSTL tags still in there, then is has definitely not run.

JSTL is by default bundled in the more fledged application servers, but not in small and simple servletcontainers like Tomcat, Jetty, etc. You'd need to drop the necessary JSTL JAR file(s) in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder or server's `/lib` folder yourself.

For more detailed background information, [see our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

By the way, your servlet doesn't extend `HttpServlet` and isn't forwarding to the JSP at all, but I'll assume it to be careless oversimplification while preparing the code for the question. If you are indeed not requesting the JSP page through the servlet, then the cause is completely different. The solution is simple: call the servlet by URL, not the JSP. Hide if necessary JSP away in `/WEB-INF` so that the enduser can never accidently call it by URL. See also [our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

That whole `<%@page import="GeneralClasses.FooClass" %>` line is also unnecessary.

Comment: thank you for the help. I was directly calling the jsp page hoping that it should work. Now i made a request dispatcher and dispatched the request to the jsp page.